# Is there a way to package more than one .NET assembly in a dll?

Tags: .net, dll, assemblies, packaging

I'd like to keep my components/assemblies clearly separated from a source code point of view but I also need in some circumstances (probably not relevant to expand) to package them in the same dll.

**Is it possible to package a number of .NET assemblies in a single dll? If so, How?**

IF possible, do you think it is a good idea? Why?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out this article : [Merging .NET assemblies using ILMerge](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mergingassemblies.aspx)

---

> As you know, traditional linking of
>   object code is no longer necessary in
>   .NET. A .NET program will usually
>   consist of multiple parts. A typical
>   .NET application consists of an
>   executable assembly, a few assemblies
>   in the program directory, and a few
>   assemblies in the global assembly
>   cache. When the program is run, the
>   runtime combines all these parts to a
>   program. Linking at compile time is no
>   longer necessary.
>
> But sometimes, it is nevertheless
>   useful to combine all parts a program
>   needs to execute into a single
>   assembly. For example, you might want
>   to simplify the deployment of your
>   application by combining the program,
>   all required libraries, and all
>   resources, into a single .exe file.

```
csc /target:library /out:ClassLibrary1.dll ClassLibrary1.cs
vbc /target:library /out:ClassLibrary2.dll ClassLibrary2.vb
vbc /target:winexe /out:Program.exe 
    /reference:ClassLibrary1.dll,ClassLibrary2.dll Program.vb
```

.

```
ilmerge /target:winexe /out:SelfContainedProgram.exe 
        Program.exe ClassLibrary1.dll ClassLibrary2.dll
```

Comment: But this produces an EXE file, not a DLL (?)

Answer (score 6):

`ILMerge` can merge two assemblies into one.

See [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingLanguagesInASingleAssemblyInVisualStudioSeamlesslyWithILMergeAndMSBuild.aspx) for information (the examples are for cross language, but it will work whatever tools built the assemblies).

Obviously any dependencies on the individual assemblies (pre-merge) will need to be updated/redirected.